# How can I switch storage locations on the fly in Django?

Tags: django, couchdb, storage

I am using CouchDB for my DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE, but I recently got another server that has a separate instance of CouchDB to be used for important files that need to be stored for a long time (for legal reasons).

The majority of the time, I will be accessing files via the default_storage, but for the times I need to access the files in the new sever, how can I switch to the new storage on the fly?

My settings currently look something like this:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'project_name.files.storage.CouchDBStorage'
COUCHDB_STORAGE_OPTIONS = {
    'server': 'http://mydomain.com:5984', 
    'database': 'storage'
}
```

To access files on the current server, I would do something like this:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

my_file = default_storage.get_document(my_object.file.name)
```

Does anyone have any experience with something like this?  This may seem unconventional, but acquiring the second server was beyond my control.

Comment: I am thinking I need to add a new storage class, similar to CouchDBStorage, and pass it options with the new server address, but then I wouldn't know how to import that storage like I am doing for the default_storage.  Could I just do it like this: from project_name.files.storage import NewCouchDBStorage